# How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, element

I read the post:  How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?
[How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

The answer given was:

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "whatever"]
```

I know this is list comprehension but I cannot break this code down and understand it.  Can someone please piece meal it for me?

---

If do the following code:I know enumerate will just create a tuple:

```
l=['a','b','c','d']
enumerate(l)
```

output:

```
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'd')
```

If there's a simpler way I'd be open to that too.

Comment: There's no rocket science in list comprehension. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "whatever"]` is equivalent to:

```
# Create an empty list
indices = []
# Step through your target list, pulling out the tuples you mention above
for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    # If the current value matches something, append the index to the list
    if value == 'whatever':
        indices.append(index)
```

The resulting list contains the index positions of each match. Taking that same `for` construct, you can actually go deeper and iterate through lists-of-lists, sending you into an Inception-esque spiral of madness:

```
In [1]: my_list = [['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four', 'two']]

In [2]: l = [item for inner_list in my_list for item in inner_list if item == 'two']

In [3]: l
Out[3]: ['two', 'two']
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
l = []
for inner_list in my_list:
  for item in inner_list:
    if item == 'two':
      l.append(item)
```

The list comprehension you include at the beginning is the most Pythonic way I can think of to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @user1527227 No problem at all, happy to help! I would suggest practicing list comprehensions until they start to 'click' - they are one of those features that you start to get a handle on and then you wonder how you could live without them :)

Comment: One of the best explanations of this I've found.

Answer (score 0):

```
indices = []
for idx, elem in enumerate(my_list):
    if elem=='whatever':
        indices.append(idx)
```