# Alternatives to index()

Tags: python

So for my project I have to allow the user to input a sentence and then input a word and find all the occourunces of the word and print the numbers. Here's what I have

```
    found = 0

sen = input("Enter the sentence you would like to break down!")
sen1 = sen.upper()
list = sen1.split()


search=input("Enter the word you want to search")
search1 = search.upper()
for search1 in list:
    found = found + 1

position=list.index(search1)



if position == 0:
    print("First word in the sentence")
if position == 1:
    print("Second word in the sentence")
if position == 2:
    print("Third word in the sentence")
if position == 3:
    print("Fourth word in the sentence")
if position == 4:
    print("Fifth word in the sentence")
if position == 5:
    print("6th word in the sentence")

else:
    position1 = position + 1
    print(position1, "th word in the sentence")
```

but it only prints the first occurunce of the word and rarely works. Any solutions?

Comment: Just a comment, you shouldn't use the variable name `list` as it is a reserved word in python. You're replacing the functionality of default functions in python with your own variables and that can lead to unintended results. You can see the [full list here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html).

Comment: `list` is a reserved keyword in python and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

Comment: `for loop` and `enumerate()` is what you are looking for probably.

Comment: [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list) and [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478974/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Comment: @zephyr: `list` isn't exactly a reserved word, otherwise you'd get a SyntaxError when you try to redefine it. (See what happens if you try to assign to `for`, `in`, or `with`). But yes, one _should_ avoid shadowing the built-in names like `list`, `str`, `dict`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `list` with `a_list`.

List of positions of a `search1` occurances:

```
positions = [idx for idx, el in enumerate(a_list) if el == search1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a great alternative which is re.finditer:

```
import re
sen = input("Enter the sentence you would like to break down!")
search = input("Enter the word you want to search")
for match in re.finditer(search, sen):
    print (match.start())
```

Comment: My guess is that this is a homework assignment and they're not supposed to use built in functions to accomplish the task.

Comment: this prints the values of where the end of the word is, not the identified word

Comment: OP asks for an alternative so I provided what is arguably the best one (:

Comment: @zephyr Don't you mean *only* use built-in functions?

Comment: Yes I suppose built-in would refer to native python functions whereas `re` functions wouldn't count as built-in. Terminology aside, they probably aren't meant to use `re`.

Answer (score 0):

Several comments have mentioned the danger of using `list` as a variable name. It's not actually a reserved word, but it *is* the name of a built-in type, and shadowing it by using it as a variable name can lead to mysterious bugs if you later wish to use this type to construct a list or test the type of an object.

A major problem with the code you posted is here:

```
search1 = search.upper()
for search1 in list:
```

The first line saves the upper-case version of the string `search` to the name `search1`. But the next line simply clobbers that with the words in `list`; it does not perform any searching operation. At the end of the `for` loop, `search1` will be equal to the last item in `list`, and that's why your code isn't doing what you expect it to when it executes `position=list.index(search1)`: you're telling it to find the position of the last word in `list`.

---

You *could* use `.index` to do what you want. To find multiple occurences you need to use a loop and pass `.index` a starting position. Eg,

```
def find_all(wordlist, word):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            i = wordlist.index(word, i) + 1
            result.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            return result
```

However, there's really not much benefit in using `.index` here.`.index` performs its scan at C speed, so it's faster than scanning in a Python loop but you probably won't notice much of a speed difference unless the list you're scanning is large.

The simpler approach is as given in Tomasz's answer. Here's a variation I wrote while Tomasz was writing his answer.

```
def ordinal(n):
    k = n % 10
    return "%d%s" % (n, "tsnrhtdd"[(n // 10 % 10 != 1) * (k < 4) * k::4])

def find_all(wordlist, word):
    return [i for i, s in enumerate(wordlist, 1) if s == word]

sen = 'this has this like this'
wordlist = sen.upper().split()

words = 'this has that like'
for word in words.split():
    pos = find_all(wordlist, word.upper())
    if pos:
        pos = ', '.join([ordinal(u) for u in pos])
    else:
        pos = 'Not found'
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(word, pos))
```

**output**

```
this: 1st, 3rd, 5th
has: 2nd
that: Not found
like: 4th
```

The code for `ordinal` was "borrowed" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007730/4014959).