# Finding the indices of matching elements in list in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, find

I have a long list of float numbers ranging from 1 to 5, called "average", and I want to return the list of indices for elements that are smaller than a or larger than b

```
def find(lst,a,b):
    result = []
    for x in lst:
        if x<a or x>b:
            i = lst.index(x)
            result.append(i)
    return result

matches = find(average,2,4)
```

But surprisingly, the output for "matches" has a lot of repetitions in it, e.g. `[2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 2, 19, 2, 10, 2, 2, 42, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, ...]`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You are using `.index()` which will only find the **first** occurrence of your value in the list. So if you have a value 1.0 at index 2, and at index 9, then `.index(1.0)` will *always* return `2`, no matter how many times `1.0` occurs in the list.

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add indices to your loop instead:

```
def find(lst, a, b):
    result = []
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x<a or x>b:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

You can collapse this into a list comprehension:

```
def find(lst, a, b):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x<a or x>b]
```

Comment: Now I totally get it. The list comprehension is really a good one, I'm still trying to adapt to this kind of compact form in Python. Your answer is excellent, thanks so much!

Comment: What's funny is that the wrong result with repetitions seems working fine for my later use, since I want to use it to extract columns of a large matrix. It seems repetitions do not affect the slicing.

Comment: You'll still get the correct values out of your list, the same values resides at index 2 and whatever later indices. But it's a bug waiting to happen, biting you at some other point in your code.

Answer (score 3):

if you're doing a lot of this kind of thing you should consider using `numpy`.

```
In [56]: import random, numpy

In [57]: lst = numpy.array([random.uniform(0, 5) for _ in range(1000)]) # example list

In [58]: a, b = 1, 3

In [59]: numpy.flatnonzero((lst > a) & (lst < b))[:10]
Out[59]: array([ 0, 12, 13, 15, 18, 19, 23, 24, 26, 29])
```

In response to Seanny123's question, I used this timing code:

```
import numpy, timeit, random

a, b = 1, 3

lst = numpy.array([random.uniform(0, 5) for _ in range(1000)])

def numpy_way():
    numpy.flatnonzero((lst > 1) & (lst < 3))[:10]

def list_comprehension():
    [e for e in lst if 1 < e < 3][:10]

print timeit.timeit(numpy_way)
print timeit.timeit(list_comprehension)
```

The numpy version is over 60 times faster.

Comment: What's the performance comparison compared to just doing a list comprehension? Also, why use `numpy.flatnonzero` over `numpy.where`?

Comment: It's over 60 times faster in my hands.  `flatnonzero` is simpler than `where`, here; you don't need to pull the array of indices out of the tuple.

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> average =  [1,3,2,1,1,0,24,23,7,2,727,2,7,68,7,83,2]
>>> matches = [i for i in range(0,len(average)) if average[i]<2 or average[i]>4]
>>> matches
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: This is not at all what the OP wanted.