# Indices of matching elements given two lists of which one has redundant entries

Tags: python, list, indexing

I've got two lists, `a` and `b`. `a` contains elements for which I would like to know the indices of matching elements in `b`. In `b`, every element is unique, unlike in `a`.

```
a = [1993, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1998, 2003, 2005, 2005]
b = [1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
```

Using the solution from [Finding the indices of matching elements in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685384/finding-the-indices-of-matching-elements-in-list-in-python/3621464#16685428):

```
matching = [match for match, element in enumerate(b) if element in a]
```

`matching` however is only `[27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 37, 39]`, but I expect it to be `[27, 27, 28, 29, 30, 30, 32, 37, 39, 39]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1993, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1998, 2003, 2005, 2005]
>>> b = [1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
>>> [b.index(x) for x in a]
[27, 27, 28, 29, 30, 30, 32, 37, 39, 39]
```

Comment: works in this case but will raise a ValueError if any value in `a` is not in `b`. `[b.index(x) for x in a if b.count(x)]` would be safer...

Comment: Sure, that entirely depends on if you want it to fail or not.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
print [b.index(i) for i in a if i in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion on Padraic Cunningham's [suggestion to use sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029123/1894317).  If instead you convert the list you're indexing off of into a dictionary, you can achieve O(1) lookup, for O(n) preprocessing:

```
a = [1993, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1998, 2003, 2005, 2005]
b = [1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]

d = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(b)}
print([d[x] for x in a])



>>> timeit("[bisect_left(b, x) for x in a]", "from __main__ import a, b; from bisect import bisect_left")
3.513558427607279
>>> timeit("[b.index(x) for x in a]", "from __main__ import a, b")
8.010070997323822
>>> timeit("d = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(b)}; [d[x] for x in a]", "from __main__ import a, b")
5.5277420695707065
>>> timeit("[d[x] for x in a]", "from __main__ import a, b, ;d = {value : index for index, value in enumerate(b)}")
1.1214096146165389
```

So, if you discount the preprocessing, you're almost 8 times faster than using `b.index` in the actual processing - which is better if you're doing lots of list `a`'s against fewer `b`'s.  Using `bisect_left` is faster if you're only doing it once, and can guarantee that `b` is monotonically ascending.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large lists making b a set will be more efficient:

```
st = set(b)
print([b.index(x) for x in a if x in st])
```

As your data is sorted and presuming all elements from a are in b you can also use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) so each index lookup is O(log n):

```
a = [1993, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1998, 2003, 2005, 2005]
b = [1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]


from bisect import bisect_left
print [bisect_left(b, x) for x in a]
[27, 27, 28, 29, 30, 30, 32, 37, 39, 39]
```

On the small dataset it runs twice as fast as just indexing:

```
In [22]: timeit [bisect_left(b, x) for x in a]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.2 µs per loop

In [23]: timeit [b.index(x) for x in a]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.84 µs per loop
```

Another option would be to use a dict to store the indexes which would mean the code would run in linear time, one pass over a and one pass over b:

```
# store all indexes as values and years as keys
indexes = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(b)}
# one pass over a accessing each index in constant time
print [indexes[x] for x in a]
[27, 27, 28, 29, 30, 30, 32, 37, 39, 39]
```

Which even on the small input set is a bit more efficient than indexing and as the a grows would be a lot more efficient:

```
In [34]: %%timeit                                                            
indexes = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(b)}
[indexes[x] for x in a]
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.54 µs per loop

In [39]: b = list(range(1966,2100))
In [40]: samp = list(range(1966,2100))
In [41]: a = [choice(samp) for _ in range(100)]

In [42]: timeit [b.index(x) for x in a 
10000 loops, best of 3: 154 µs per loop   
In [43]: %%timeit                      
indexes = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(b)}
[indexes[x] for x in a]
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Now you just look it up twice, once in a set and once in a list. That's an improvement only if it is not in the list.

Comment: @LennartRegebro. So an 0(1) lookup is slower than a linear fo the numerous values that don't appear in b? You think if you have 1000000 elements in b that using a list is better?

Comment: No, but if it is in the list, which OP's question presumes, then you don't need the if test at all. If it mostly is in the list, then trapping the error would be better.

Comment: @LennartRegebro. well I added a bisect method which is more efficient than indexing

Comment: True, if we know b is ordered, that will speed it up.