# How to find the indices of items in a list, which are present in another list?

Tags: python, list

I want to essentially use one list ie.

```
L = [10, 10, 100, 10, 17, 15]
```

and using another list

```
R = [10, 15]
```

want to return

```
N = [0, 1, 3, 5] // indices of L that return the values in R
```

I tried using `L.index()` to get the indices but that only returns the first value. I then tried running a for loop over `L` and using `L.index(R[0])` every time, but similarly that only returns the first indices it finds at.

```
 for i in range(len(L)):
       j = R[i]
       N.append(L.index(j))
 return N
```

This would return index out of range which makes sense, but how do I get it to run through the `L`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685384/finding-the-indices-of-matching-elements-in-list-in-python

Comment: Replace the `if x == "whatever"` part with `if x in R`. You can improve the efficiency if you convert `R` to a set first `R = set(R)`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yeah nearly, but they only similarly account for only checking one value ie L.index(#) at a time can't pass a L in. Got it below, thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
N = []

for i in range(len(L)):

    if L[i] in R:
        N.append(i)
```

or avoid indexing by using `enumerate`

```
N = []

for i, l in enumerate(L):
    
    if l in R:
        N.append(i)
```

or with a generator

```
N = [i for i in range(len(L)) if L[i] in R]
```

or with arrays

```
import numpy as np

N=np.where(np.isin(L,R))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[i for i,l in enumerate(L) if l in R]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = []  
for i, num in enumerate(L):  
    if num in R:  
        N.append(i)
```