# Simple Way to Check Each List Element for Match with Particular String in Python

Tags: python, list, logical-operators

I have the following list in Python:

```
my_list = ["yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"]
```

I want to return a list of logical values, being `True` in case the corresponding list element in my_list is equal to "yes" and `False` in case the corresponding list element in my_list is equal to "no".

Desired output:

```
my_list_logical = [True, True, False, True, False, True]
```

I'm usually programming in R, and in R this could be done easily with the following code:

```
my_list == "yes"
```

I found a Python solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685384/finding-the-indices-of-matching-elements-in-list-in-python). However, the solution of this thread is very complicated, and I cannot believe that this is so much more complicated in Python than in R.

Is there a simple way on how to return a list of logicals based on my input vector?

Comment: removed R-tag, since this is a python question..

Comment: `my_list_logical = [x == "yes" for x in my_list]`

Comment: @Wimpel OK, thanks! I thought I'd add it because I'm comparing Python with R, but removing it is fine.

Comment: Or `my_list_logical = map(lambda x: x == "yes", my_list)`

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for the quick responses, and the numerous very nice solutions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
my_list = ["yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"]

logical = [item=='yes' for item in my_list]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[True, True, False, True, False, True]
```

Or, you can even use map:

```py
logical = list(map(lambda x: x=='yes', my_list))
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best answer is to use the package `numpy`. Numpy arrays act similarly to R vectors.

```
import numpy as np
my_list = np.array(["yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"])
my_list == "yes"
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False,  True])
```

Comment: It feels rather over-engineered to pull in numpy just to run a list comprehension/equivalent of `map`.

Comment: Well, if you want behavior similar to R, thats what you have to do. If you are coming from R you are probably working in data so I would imagine you already have numpy installed.

Comment: The question was specifically about a regular Python list and they didn't ask about a way to make it identical to R, just a simple way to do it. A list comprehension is simple and provides the result they asked for. I'm not saying the answer should be removed or anything, but it's probably not going to get much interest.

Comment: Fair enough, I think using numpy is simpler, particularly if you come from R.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map()` function with syntax `map(<function>, <iterable>)`. However you will have to code it into a `list()` to yield the results, for example:

```
my_list = ["yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"]
my_list_logical = list(map(lambda x: x == "yes", my_list))
print(my_list_logical)
```

Output

```
[True, True, False, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may very much use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ["yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"]
result = [item == "yes" for item in my_list]
```

Which yields

```
[True, True, False, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and this is the most logical way I can think of

```py
my_list = ["yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"]
my_list_logical = []
for i in my_list:
   if i == “yes”:
      my_list_logical.append(True)
   else:
      my_list_logical.append(False)
```