# Python loops iteration to get a list of all indices of an element in a list

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, indices

I am trying to write a function which consumes a string and a character and produces a list of indices for all occurrences of that character in that string.

So far this is what I have, but it always gives me [].

```
def list_of_indices(s,char):

    string_lowercase = s.lower()
    sorted_string = "".join(sorted(string_lowercase))
    char_list = list(sorted_string)

    for x in char_list:
          a = []
          if x == char:

             a.append(char_list.index(x))
          return a
```

I don't understand why this does not yield the answer. And it has to be a list of non-empty length.

Anyone aware of how to get the indices for all occurrences?

Comment: Related: [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

You're returning on the first iteration of your `for`-loop. Make sure the `return` statement is outside the scope of the loop.

Also, be sure to put `a = []` *before* the `for`-loop. Otherwise, you're effectively resetting the list on each iteration of loop.

There is also a problem with `char_list.index(x)`. This will always return the index of the *first* occurrence of `x`, which isn't what you want. You should keep track of an index as you are looping (e.g. with [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)).

And I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the sort; looping through the original string should be sufficient.

Lastly, note that you can loop over a string directly; you don't need to convert it to a list (i.e. `char_list` is unnecessary).

---

Note that your task can be accomplished with a simple [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> s = 'abcaba'
>>> char = 'a'
>>> 
>>> [i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c == char]  # <--
[0, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Which would mean that it should be aligned with for or define?

Comment: @user3457606 It should be at the same indentation level as `for`.

Comment: I do realize that it could be solved through list comprehension but I specifically require a loops solution.

Comment: @user3457606 Sure, the beginning of my answer still stands. Plus the comprehension might be helpful for others who visit this page with the same problem.

Comment: Yes. Is there aq way we can do this with loops alone?

Comment: If it is indented with for, it only produces [2] if this examples is run: list_of_indices("abcc","c") => [2]

Comment: @user3457606 You had more problems than I thought, it seems. See the revised answer.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this result without using enumerate()?

Comment: @user3457606 Set some variable to 0 and use it as a counter instead (i.e. increment it on each iteration of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it using a quick [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
def list_of_indicies(s, char):
    return [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c == char]
```

or by using a for loop instead:

```
def list_of_indicies(s, char):
    results = list()

    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == char:
            results.append(i)

    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a on the first loop of your for loop iteration.

**Change for loop to this for starters:**

```
def list_of_indices(s,char):
    string_lowercase = s.lower()
    a = []
    i = 0
    for x in string_lowercase:
        if x == char:
            a.append(i)
        i+=1
    return a
```

Comment: This only gives a list of the same index of the character the number of times it appears in the list. Also, is there a way to get the answer while staying away from enumerate() or list comprehension, strictly loops?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I missunderstood the question, can you please provide an example of an input and an output of your desired function ? This would make it much easier.

Comment: so lets say if i have list_of_indices("abcc","c") => [2,3]