# numpy where compare arrays as a whole

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `x=np.array([[0,1,2,],[0,0,0],[3,4,0],[1,2,3]])`, and I want to get the index where x=[0,0,0], i.e. 1. I tried `np.where(x==[0,0,0])` resulting in `(array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2]))`. How can I get the desired answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @transcranial solution, you can use `np.all()` to do the job. But `np.all()` is slow, so if you apply it to a large array, speed will be your concern.

To test for a specific value or a specific range, I would do like this.

```
x = np.array([[0,1,2],[0,0,0],[3,4,0],[1,2,3],[0,0,0]])

condition = (x[:,0]==0) & (x[:,1]==0) & (x[:,2]==0)
np.where(condition)
# (array([1, 4]),)
```

It's a bit ugly but it almost twice as fast as `np.all()` solution.

```
In[23]: %timeit np.where(np.all(x == [0,0,0], axis=1) == True)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.5 µs per loop
In[22]: %timeit np.where((x[:,0]==0)&(x[:,1]==0)&(x[:,2]==0))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.57 µs per loop
```

And you can test not only for equality but also a range.

```
condition = (x[:,0]<3) & (x[:,1]>=1) & (x[:,2]>=0)
np.where(condition)
# (array([0, 3]),)
```

Comment: when x gets bigger (more rows) this time difference becomes even bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Bit expensive likely but
`x.tolist().index([0,0,0])`
should work

To adapt to get all matching indices instead of one, use

```
xL = x.tolist()
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(xL) if x == [0,0,0]]
```

(inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294205/399573))

Comment: i don't think would work if x had more than one [0,0,0].

Comment: @rivu this only returns the first one, can repeatedly apply to get all of them

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a bit to see if there is a numpy based solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,1,2],[0,0,0],[3,4,0],[1,2,3]])
np.where(np.all(x == [0,0,0], axis=1) == True)[0].tolist()
# outputs [1]
```

`np.all` tests for equality for all elements along `axis=1`, which outputs `array([False, True, False, False])` in this case. Then use `np.where` to get the index where this is true.