# Find 5 consecutive numbers in numpy array by row, ignore duplicates

Tags: numpy

I have the following array (3 decks of 7 cards). They are sorted by row and I want to see if there are 5 consecutive numbers. The below code works but has a mistake: when there is a duplicate (like in row 1) the result is incorrect:

```
cards=
[[ 12.   6.   6.   5.   4.   2.   1.]
 [ 12.   9.   6.   6.   1.   1.   1.]
 [  6.   6.   1.   1.   0.   0.   0.]]

cardAmount=cards[0,:].size
has4=cards[:,np.arange(0,cardAmount-4)]-cards[:,np.arange(cardAmount-3,cardAmount)]
isStraight=np.any(has4 == 4, axis=1)
```

has4 (shows if there is a difference of 4 between any of the cards 5 positions apart)

```
[[  8.   4.   5.]
 [ 11.   8.   5.]
 [  6.   6.   1.]]
```

isStraight checks if any of the rows contains a 4, which means there is a straight. Result is incorrect for the first row because the duplicates are not ignored.

```
[ True False False]
```

The difficulty is that there is no way in numpy to do a np.unique with return_counts=True on a by row basis, as the results would have different lengths.

Any suggestions are appreciated. It has to be numpy only (or pandas if the speed is not compromised).

Comment: When I've done card hand classification, I compared the sorted numbers to `range(5)` or looked at the differences (which would a string of 1s).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Could you use a sample case that has 5 consec. numbers and also has duplicates in at least one row? Also, please add expected o/p for such a case.

Comment: yes that would also count as a straight in poker

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution. Is there a way to make it even simpler?

```
iterations=3
cardAmount=cards[0,:].size
counts=(cards[:,:,None] == np.arange(12,0,-1)).sum(1) # occurences of each cards
present=counts
present[present>1]=1
s1=np.sum(present[:,0:5], axis=1)
s2=np.sum(present[:,1:6], axis=1)
s3=np.sum(present[:,2:7], axis=1)
s=np.stack((s1,s2,s3)).T
s[s < 5] = -1
s[s == 6] = 5
s[s ==7] = 5
s_index=np.argmax(s,axis=1)
straight=s[np.arange(iterations),s_index]>=0
```