# Declarative way to return all indices of matching elements for each element in numpy?

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

Say I have an array:

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
```

I want to get an array `indices` where each element `indices[i]` is the list of indices having values equal to the value at `arr[i]`. i.e., `indices` should be

```
[[0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 3], [0, 1, 4]]
```

It'd be easy to do this using loops or iterators, but I want a declarative numpy solution. I feel like there must be some clear/fast/concise way to get the output I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30003565/14923227
It includes a vectorized solution.

Comment: @Kevin : I saw this one while searching. It's closely related, but I thought that there would probably be a way to get output in the exact form that I'm looking for in at most a couple of lines.

(I like ELinda's solution, but wanted to leave the question open for a bit in case anyone had a way to do it without using lambdas.)

Comment: I have a solution without lambdas. Gimme a couple of minutes

Comment: A list of lists that differ in length is not a valid numpy array.  Don't expect a simple numpy solution.

Comment: @hpaulj. `np.split` is magical

Comment: @user904890. I've updated my answer. There was an error in the `axis` argument.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, and like most magic, there's a niden slight-of-hand.  `split` iterates through a bunch of slices.

Comment: @hpaulj. Of course. It's just a lot faster to do that once than to call `where` or `nonzero` over and over. The goal is to minimize the python level iteration since you can't get rid of it entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is going to be a list (or worse, an array of objects), since your output is ragged in the general case. If you are OK with having each index corresponding to a repeated element point to the same underlying array, you can so something like the following.

The gist is to take a hint from [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), which is a sort-based operation. Instead of using `np.unique`, we can use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) combined with some fancy index math to get the job done.

First, you get an array with `[0, 1, 4], [2, 3]` as the elements. This will be a 1D array of objects. Actually, if the split list is non-ragged, `elements` will recombine into a 2D array, but it doesn't matter because it will not affect the intended interface.

```
idx = np.argsort(arr)
split_points = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr[idx])) + 1
elements = np.array(np.split(idx, split_points))
```

Next you can index `elements` to produce the full array of objects.

```
inverse_index = np.argsort(idx)
counts = np.diff(np.r_[0, split_points, len(arr)])
result = np.repeat(elements, counts, axis=0)[inverse_index]
```

`result` will be a 2D array if you have equal numbers of each unique element. You can choose to turn it into a list if you want.

Notice that the last part works because `np.argsort` is its own inverse: the index that puts a sorted array into its original unsorted order is the argsort of the argsort. So we've implemented most of the features of `np.unique` (`inverse_index`, `counts`) with intermediate results to make your specific application possible. To complete `np.unique`, the forward index is `np.r_[0, split_points]`, and the actual unique values are given by `arr[np.r_[0, split_points]]`.

You can shorten the code from 6 lines to about 3 without recomputing any of the necessary arrays more than once. At the same time, you can say goodbye to any semblance of legibility that was there before:

```
idx = np.argsort(arr)
split_points = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr[idx])) + 1
result = np.repeat(np.array(np.split(idx, split_points)), np.diff(np.r_[0, split_points, len(arr)]), axis=0)[np.argsort(idx)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1])
f = lambda i: np.where(arr == i)
result = np.array(list(map(f, arr)))
```

result is:

```
array([[array([0, 1, 4])],
       [array([0, 1, 4])],
       [array([2, 3])],
       [array([2, 3])],
       [array([0, 1, 4])]], dtype=object)
```