# Splitting an array according input offset values, but leaving duplicated in a same chunk

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Given a list of indexes (offset values) according which splitting a numpy array, I would like to adjust it so that the splitting does not occur on duplicate values.
This means duplicate values will be in one chunk only.

I have worked out following piece of code, which gives the result, but I am not super proud of it. I would like to stay in numpy world and use vectorized numpy functions as much as possible.
But to check the indexes (offset values) I use a `for` loop, and store the result in a list.

Do you have any idea how to vectorize the 2nd part?

If this can help, `ar` is an ordered array.
(I am not using this info in below code).

```py
import numpy as np
import vaex as vx

ar = np.array([8,8,8,10,11,11,13,14,15,15,18,19,20,21,22,22,22,22,22,22])
offsets = np.array([0,2,4,9,11,13,15,len(ar)])

_, unique_ind = np.unique(ar, return_index=True, return_inverse=False)
dup_ind = np.diff(unique_ind, append=len(ar))
dup_start = unique_ind[dup_ind > 1]
dup_end = dup_start + dup_ind[dup_ind > 1]
print(f'initial offsets: {offsets}')
#print(f'dup start: {dup_start}')
#print(f'dup end: {dup_end}')

temp = []
for off in offsets:
    for ind in range(len(dup_start)):
        if off > dup_start[ind] and off < dup_end[ind]:
            off = dup_start[ind]
            break
    temp.append(off)

# Remove duplicates
offsets = list(dict.fromkeys(temp))
print(f'modified offsets: {offsets}')
```

Results

```py
initial offsets: [ 0  2  4  9 11 13 15 20]
modified offsets: [0, 4, 8, 11, 13, 14, 20]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building upon @richardec's answer, here is a possible solution, in case it can help others.

```py
import numpy as np

def adjust_offsets(values, offsets) -> np.ndarray:
    # Creates bins describing when duplicates start and when they end.
    _, indexes, counts = np.unique(values, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
    duplicates = counts>1
    dup_starts = indexes[duplicates]
    dup_ends = dup_starts + counts[duplicates]
    # Zipping starts and ends.
    # Bins of duplicates are interlayed with bins of unique values.
    bins = np.dstack((dup_starts,dup_ends)).flatten()
    # Set start of bin for offsets falling in a bin.
    off_binned = np.digitize(offsets, bins, right=True)
    return np.unique(np.where((off_binned%2)==0,offsets,bins[off_binned-1]))

# Test setup 1 / starting with no duplicates
# idx:         0,1,2,3,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
ar = np.array([4,5,8,8,8,10,11,11,13,14,15,15,18,19,20,21,22,22,22,22,22,22])
offsets = np.array([0,2,4,9,11,14,18,len(ar)-1])
off_adjusted = adjust_offsets(ar, offsets)
ref = np.array([ 0,  2,  9, 10, 14, 16])
assert np.array_equal(off_adjusted, ref)

# Test setup 2 / starting with duplicates
# idx:         0,1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
ar = np.array([8,8,8,10,11,11,13,14,15,15,18,19,20,21,22,22,22,22,22,22])
offsets = np.array([0,2,4,9,11,13,15,len(ar)-1])
off_adjusted = adjust_offsets(ar, offsets)
ref = np.array([ 0,  4,  8, 11, 13, 14])
assert np.array_equal(off_adjusted, ref)
```

I use 2 tests as a previous version I come up with would not work in case the array was not starting with duplicates.

In 2 sentences, the algorithm follows the logic:

- if an offset value (index) fall in a bin defined by [start of duplicate, end of duplicate], then it is reset to 'start of duplicate'.
- if not, it is unmodified

There is possibly faster, as I could see from this related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780952/4442753) that `np.diff` is faster than `np.unique` and I think one can obtain the same kind of information with `np.diff`. I started assessing this possibility, but it grew too complex for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to clamp the offsets into bins:

```
ar = np.array([8,8,8,10,11,11,13,14,15,15,18,22,22,22,22,22,22])
offsets = np.array([0,2,4,9,13,15,len(ar)])

_, unique_ind = np.unique(ar, return_index=True, return_inverse=False)
dup_ind = np.diff(unique_ind, append=len(ar))
dup = np.append(unique_ind[dup_ind > 1], len(ar))

offsets = dup[np.digitize(offsets, dup) - 1]
```

Output:

```
>>> offsets
array([ 0,  0,  4,  8, 11, 11, 17])

>>> np.unique(offsets)
array([ 0,  4,  8, 11, 17])
```

It can very likely be compressed into much less code (1 or 2 lines probably), but I figured that you really just want the loop eliminated, so I though I'd submit what I've found.

Comment: Thanks! No, this code is not quite right, and my example was not complete. I have completed it to include a 'normal' case when an offset does not fall on a duplicate value. In this case, we simply keep it. I tried with your code, and value is not kept.