# Python: How to check the occurrences of a number in a list and the list positions it occurs in

Tags: python, list, position

say I have a list, x:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,1]
```

How do I search this list so that I can find the number of occurrences of a number and the list position it occurs in?

I know about using the method `x.count(num)`, but this only shows number of occurrences not list position. 
Thanks

Comment: `index` will do that, e.g. `x.index(3)` gives `2`. It only returns the first index however.

Comment: is there a way to do the same sort of operation but make it return more than just the first index?

Comment: There certainly is! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a new list to store the occurrence positions, And the length of new list is the count.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
>>> y = [ i for i in xrange(len(x)) if x[i] == 1 ]
>>> y
[0, 4]
>>> len(y)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just play with Counter..

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x=[1,2,3,4,1]
>>> Counter(x)
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
>>> {y:[i for i,j in enumerate(x) if j == y] for y in Counter(x)}
{1: [0, 4], 2: [1], 3: [2], 4: [3]}
```