# Find all occurrences of a word in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to be able to identify all of the positions where a word appears in a sentence.

For example: Hello my name is Ben and his name is Fred.

If I input 'name' it should return: This word occurs in the places: 3 and 8

Below is my code however it will only return the first value.

```
text = input('Please type your sentence: ')
sentence = text.split()
word= input('Thank-you, now type your word: ')

if word in sentence:
            print ('This word occurs in the places:', sentence.index(word)+1)
elif word not in sentence:
            print ('Sorry, '+word+' does not appear in the sentence.')
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 2):

This comprehension should do it:

```
[i+1 for i, w in enumerate(sentence) if w == word]
```

(+1 because you want first word to be 1 not 0)

Full example:

```
text = input('Please type your sentence: ')
sentence = text.split()
word = input('Thank-you, now type your word: ')

if word in sentence:
    print ('This word occurs in the places:')
    print([i+1 for i, w in enumerate(sentence) if w == word])
elif word not in sentence:
    print ('Sorry, ' + word + ' does not appear in the sentence.')
```

Comment: I just realized this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6294205/4653485

Comment: Thank-you but in the compression I need to use the variable 'word' as apposed to the string 'name'. This is so a user can input any word to find a match?

Comment: Right. I edited my answer to fix this. I just tested the comprehension on a simplified example, not the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with simple list comprehension and enumerate function to find the index. Finally add 1 to match your expected index.

```
sec = 'Hello my name is Ben and his name is Fred.'
search = input('What are you looking for? ')
print ([i + 1 for i, s in enumerate(sec.split()) if s == search])
```

Comment: Yes you can do that. Just take input from the user and store it a variable and later you can use it for the comparison. see the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with an if. You must have one loop, like this:

```
occurrences = []

for word in sentence:
    if word == target_word:
        occurrences.append(sentence.index(word)+1)
```

You will have all the occurrences in the array 'occurrences' to print your sentence or you can change 'occurrences' for a 'print' sentence, as your preference.

Please, note that I hasn't run this code, check if it is correct spelled.

Good luck!