# searching index of tuple from list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
tupleList = [('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('a','b'), ('a','b'), ('e','f')]
```

I want to find index of `('a','b')` in tupleList.

I am trying the following:

```
idx = np.where(tupleList == ('a','b'))
```

but it gives an empty array.

Desired output would be

```
idx = [0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Lists and tuples don't support the same operations as NumPy arrays; for example, `tupleList == ('a', 'b')` isn't an elementwise comparison. A list of tuples might not be the best data structure to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[i for i, t in enumerate(tupleList) if t == ('a', 'b')]
```

yields

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

see [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)