# Index of multiple minimum elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I want a list

```
a = [2,4,5,2]
```

to give

```
b = [0, 3]
```

I know how to do it for when there is only a single min element, but not multiple min elements.
example:

```
b = a.index(min(a))
```

This will give me `b = 0`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the minimum value, then iterate the list with index using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions#enumerate) to find the minimum values:

```
>>> a = [2,4,5,2]
>>> min_value = min(a)
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == min_value]
[0, 3]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Comment: @McGrady, just voted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using numpy in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,4,5,2])
np.where(a==a.min())
```