# How do i move the offset of the 'index' method of 'list'

Tags: python, list, offset

i know that the index function work like this:

```
list = ['dog','cat','pizza','trump', 'computer', 'trump']
print list.index('trump')
```

the output will be 3.
but now i want him for print the other 'trump' string,
that come after 2 objects. but if i will do the same command:

```
print list.index('trump')
```

he will print 3 again - the first trump he see.
so how do i move the 'offset' of the index function, so she will detect the other trump, in the index 5?
thanks lot you guys!!

Comment: are you looking to print all the indexes where your string occur?

Comment: You might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Comment: or the last one?

Comment: BTW, don't use the variable name `list` as it shadows the built-in function `list()`

Answer (score 5):

`list.index` takes a 2nd start argument:

```
>>> lst = ['dog','cat','pizza','trump', 'computer', 'trump']
>>> lst.index('trump') # 1st index
3
>>> lst.index('trump',4) # 2nd index
5
>>> lst.index('trump',lst.index('trump')+1) # 2nd index
5
```

Or if you want all indexes, use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [idx for idx,item in enumerate(lst) if item == 'trump']
[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just note the first index where the string appears, and pass the extra parameter to `index` the second time:

```
l = ['dog','cat','pizza','trump', 'computer', 'trump']
i = l.index("trump")
print(i)
print(l.index("trump",i+1))
```

I get:

```
3
5
```

from the inline doc, you can pass an optional start & stop value:

> index(...)
>
> L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
>       Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

(in a general case you have to protect your call to `index` by a `try/except ValueError` block in case the value is not in the list and act accordingly)

Note that `start` can be negative. If negative, the index is computed from the end of the list instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of all indices for an entry in your list, you can do something like this:

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(list) if x == "key"]
```

Answer (score 1):

create a shortened version of the list.

```
list=['dog','cat','pizza','trump', 'computer', 'trump']
print list.index('trump')
list = list[list.index('trump')+1:]
print list.index('trump')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['dog','cat','pizza','trump', 'computer', 'trump']
i = [n for n, item in enumerate(l) if item == 'trump'] #find all indices

# print the result
for n in i:
   print n, l[n]

3 trump
5 trump
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...it work like charm.

Actually in your problem iteration executes only once even in for loop it wont work(not work for me even after `iter` and `next()` used)so I tried with `while` then I realize it is the game of iteration so put `while` in `try` with `while 1:` to start with iteration `1`and index method does a linear search, and stops at the first matching item. If no matching item is found, it raises a `ValueError` exception.

## CODE

```
list = ['dog','cat','pizza','trump', 'computer', 'trump']
value = "trump"
i = -1
try:
    while 1: # Start with Iteration 1 never 0
        i = list.index(value, i+1)
        print(value,"at", i)
except ValueError: # No matching item is found.
    pass
```

## OUTPUT

```
trump at 3
trump at 5
```

Comment: Found another easiest way to get common string in list
#CODE
`for idx,val in enumerate(l):
 if val=='trump':
  print(idx,val)`
#OUTPUT
`3 trump
5 trump`