# How can I find the minimum value from a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, math, min

```
import sys
trig = []
base, area = input().strip().split(' ')
base, area = [int(base), int(area)]
for i in range(1,area+1):
    form = abs(((base*i)/2)-area)
    trig.append(form)

for i in range(1,area+1):
    form = abs(((base*i)/2)-area)
    if form == min(trig):
        print(i)
```

I am trying to find the minimum value from the first `for` loop but I would like to avoid using a list since I want the program to run faster. How can I do this without using lists?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't the first value always be the smallest one...?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You could store that min value in a variable, like `minTrig = min(trig)` and then use that value in `if form == minTrig:`. By doing that you will not be calling `min()` every time in the second for loop.

Comment: The first one will not always have the smallest value. I just tried running a small test and the minumum value comes later on in the trig array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go on limb and try to guess what you want based from your code - this will essentially keep just one variable and check for the minimum on each loop (and update accordingly, if needed):

```
base, area = input().strip().split()
base, area = int(base), int(area)

min_pos = 1
min_trig = abs(base / 2 - area)  # calculate the first immediately
for i in range(2, area + 1):  # loop from the second...
    form = abs((base * i) / 2 - area)
    if form < min_trig:
        min_pos = i
        min_trig = form

print(min_pos)
```

**UPDATE**

As stated in the comments, the above will find indexes only for a single minimum so it would be correct only if there is one minimum. If you need a list of minimums you can do as following:

```
base, area = input().strip().split()
base, area = int(base), int(area)

min_pos = [1]  # initialize the first index as a minimum immediately
min_trig = abs(base / 2 - area)  # calculate the first trig as a minimum immediately
for i in range(2, area + 1):  # loop from the second...
    trig = abs((base * i) / 2 - area)
    if trig == min_trig:
        min_pos.append(i)
    elif trig < min_trig:
        min_pos = [i]
        min_trig = trig

print(min_pos)  # prints you a list of all minimum positions
```

That way you don't have to store everything in a separate list nor you need to do double loops. Pure O(N) solution.

Comment: this solution does not work since the OP wanted the (index + 1) for all occurrences of the minimum value. The least time complex solution to this is O(N) since the list must first be created, then the minimum value must be found.

Comment: Mea culpa, couldn't read the OP's mind... He wants the position, which is even easier, updated above.

Comment: Instead of making min_pos a single index, if it is an array, it can account for multiple indices. change `min_pos = i` to `min_pos.append(i)`. I did something very similar in my solution.

Comment: That wouldn't help it - the above works only for singular solutions as it doesn't have the power to predict the future. If `min_pos` was a list it would contain multiple _indexes of minimum values at the time_.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what your code does now, I have created another version of your segment that essentially does the same thing. I tested it out with the input string `"5 16"` and it seems to be working. The code I used is as following:

```
import sys
trig = []
base, area = input().strip().split(' ')
base, area = [int(base), int(area)]
minTrig = (base * area) / 2 # set an upperbound on minTrig so that the max value in the trig array will be less than this value.
for i in range(1,area+1):
    form = abs(((base * i) / 2) - area)
    trig.append(form)
    minTrig = min(minTrig, form)
indices = [i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(trig) if x == minTrig]
print(indices)
```

This uses list comprehension to create a new array of all the indices at which the minimum number occurs.

The code used to find all occurrences of the minimum value element can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list).

When I test out my code with `"5 16"` the output is `[6, 7]`.