# return all the indices where element is present in a python list

Tags: python

This return only the first index value where the char is present in the list. I need all the indices where char is present.

```
  def find_loc(char):
    for sub_list in chunks:
        if char in sub_list:
                return chunks.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(char)
```

Comment: Flagging for "Very low quality". Have a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Index method returns the first index value encountered.

Help on method_descriptor:

```
index(...)
    L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
```

Comment: is there any method by which i can get all the index values,

Comment: use [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) and put a condition.

Comment: @shivamsinghal check the above link for enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet:

```
def indexes(iterable, obj):
    encounters = []
    for i in range(len(iterable)):
        if iterable[i] == obj:
            encounters.append(i)
    return encounters
```