# How to find the different indexes of the same value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

For example I have:

```
l = [4, 1 ,3, 4, 7 , 4]
```

if I use

```
l.index(4)
```

it returns back 0

How do I get it to return back 0, 3, 5?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = [4, 1 ,3, 4, 7 , 4]
index = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == 4]
print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x[0] for x in enumerate(l) if x[1] == 4]
```