# check how many items are there in that list and what are they? and return the respective values for the items present in that list

Tags: python

I am having below list:

```
platform = ['0/0','0/1','0/2','0/3']
```

from the above list i want to return a value for each item in that list.

```
if '0/0' in platform:
    return value1
if '0/1' in platform:
    return value2
```

and so on. but if i use this code it will stop when it finds the first match, for second and third values it will not match.

But i want to check how many items are there in that list and what are they ?and return the respective values for the items present in that list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Comment: so what would be your desired output for the example input you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Sathya Varna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6483003/sathya-varna),

I think you are looking for [Data Structures/Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

If I understand correctly from your description you want to know how many elements you have in your list (e.g. Array), but after that you want to link your list with a value for each element. If this is the case you can link each element (key) with a (value) and create a dictionary.

By doing so you can call a value based on the key.

Sample of code bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

dictionary = { 'O/O': 'value1',
               '0/1': 'value2',
               '0/2': 'value3',
               '0/3': 'value4' }

print "Length : %d" % len (dictionary)
print dictionary.keys()
print dictionary.values()
print "dictionary['0/2']: ", dictionary['0/2']
```

If this is not what you are looking for, provide us more information on what is the expected output.

Hope this helps, BR.