# How to find the index of all minimum elements in a numpy array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array

```
a = np.array([0,2,3,4,5,1,9,0,0,7,9,0,0,0]).reshape(7,2)
```

I want to find out the indices of all the times the minimum element (here 0) occurs in the 2nd column. Using argmin I can find out the index of when 0 is occurring for the first time. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are currently simply expecting us to solve the problem **for you**. **PLEASE** give it a try **on your own**, and if you have no clue please search online and learn the basics and then show us what you've achieved - and if you get stuck along the way, feel free to come back and ask for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/q/6294179/9303824

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.flatnonzero` on `a[:, 1]==np.min(a)` is the most starightforward way:

```
In [3]: idxs = np.flatnonzero(a[:, 1]==np.min(a))

In [4]: idxs
Out[4]: array([3, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

After you reshaped your array it looks like this:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 1],
       [9, 0],
       [0, 7],
       [9, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

You can get all elements that are of the same value by using `np.where`. IN your case the following would work:

```
np.where(a.T[-1] == a.argmin())
# This would give you (array([3, 5, 6]),)
```

What happens here is that you create a transposed view on the array. This means you can easily access the columns. The term view here means that the `a` array itself is not changed for that. This leaves you with:

```
a.T

array([[0, 3, 5, 9, 0, 9, 0],
       [2, 4, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0]])
```

From this you select the last line (i.e. the last column of `a`) by using the index `-1`. Now you have the array

```
array([2, 4, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0])
```

on which you can call `np.where(condititon)`, which gives you all indices for which the condition is true. In your case the condition is

```
a.T[-1] == a.argmin()
```

which gives you all entries in the selected line of the transposed array that have the same value as `np.argmin(a)` which, as you said, is `0` in your case.

Comment: Why do you need the explicit `.view()`? Doesn't numpy create views automatically? (transpose is also a view AFAIK).

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting an answer to your question by clicking on the tick mark next to the up/ downvote arrows. This marks your question as resolved.