# find indexes of all None items in a list in python

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I have a list of strings, some of them are None.
i want to get a new list of all the Indexes of None.

```
list = ['a', 'b', None, 'c' ,None, 'd']
```

using the function index

```
n = list.index(None)
```

will only return the first appearance, n= 2, while i want to see n= [2,4].
thanks you.

Comment: dir(builtins) - will show that using list as var name is bad idea

Comment: @Drako Yeah, for every builtin method!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
l=[i for i,v in enumerate(list) if v == None]
```

Or [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
l=[i for i in range(len(list)) if list[i] == None]
```

Both cases:

```
print(l)
```

Is:

```
[2,4]
```

**Big Note:** it is not good to name variables a existing method name, that overwrites it, (now it's `list`), so i would prefer it as `l` (or something)

I recommend the first example because `enumerate` is easy, efficient.

Comment: @MorZamir Now you've got more than 15 reputation, so you can up-vote if you want :-)

Comment: funny to see your comment today for having 15 reputation, after receiving a badge for first asked question with 1k views.

Comment: @MorZamir Wow congratulations for getting it, i have it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Faster way. Very useful in case of long list.

```
list = ['a', 'b', None, 'c' ,None, 'd']
import numpy as np
print(np.where(np.array(list) == None)[0])
```

Output :

```
[2 4]
```

In case you need list of index :

```
print(np.where(np.array(list) == None)[0].tolist())
>>> [2, 4]
```

Comment: Note, it has a warning ``FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.``, in the future, this will not work.

Comment: No warnings in python 2.7

Comment: @MEdwin Oh i didn't test on python 3, so?

Comment: @Black Thunder . I don't know why but numpy arrays are printed without commas. That's why I have used .tolist() method

Comment: The first method gives me nothing except an empty list.

Comment: @Lalit For python 3.6 it does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something different but it doesn't use list comprehension:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', None, 'c' ,None, 'd']
>>> out = []
>>> for _ in range(l.count(None)):
    out.append(l.index(None))
    l[l.index(None)] = "w"


>>> out
[2, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use list comprehension:

```
[i for i in list_ if i == None]
```