# Finding index of characters in a string

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
def indexes(word, letter):
    acc=[]
    for i in word:
        for g in letter:
            if g in i:
                acc.append(word.index(i))
    return acc
```

if i call the function `indexes("mississippi","s")` the following is returned:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

So, the function returns the correct amount of letters, but it only returns the first index of where "`s`" is found and fills the list with that index. Any reason why the list doesn't return the index of each "`s`"?

Comment: because `word.index(i)` will always return the first index of the letter. and you're using the same `word` in each of the loops

Answer (score 0):

The python `index()` method only returns the first index if an element is present more than once.

As stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294205/10534842

> You can use a list comprehension:
>
> ```
> indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "whatever"]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`index` will always return the first index. You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in your function to get the indices of each letter as you iterate:

```
def indexes(word, letter):
    acc=[]
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c == letter:
            acc.append(i)
    return acc

print(indexes("mississippi","s"))
# [2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do with List comprehension,

```
def indexes(word, letter):
    return [pos for pos, char in enumerate(word) if char == letter]

print(indexes("mississippi","s"))
```