# How can I find the index of each occurrence of an item in a python list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, enumerate

I want to search through a python list and print out the index of each occurrence.

```py
a = ['t','e','s','t']
a.index('t')
```

The above code only gives me the first occurrence's index.

Comment: you would have to loop through the list yourself and record the indices

Comment: Do you know about `enumerate(a)` and list comprehensions?

Comment: I've heard about `enumerate()`, but I did not know how to use it in this way.

Comment: CoderDude: sure. Anytime you find yourself writing `for i in range(len(something))` it's always a code smell for `enumerate(something)`. And since that avoids needing a loop, it suggests a list comprehension (possibly with a condition).

Comment: Do you only want to find occurrences of the item 't' (as your code implies), or all elements in the list (as your title implies)? The latter is more generalizable for the rest of us. Can you please fix either your title or your code?

Comment: This question was asked when I was very inexperienced with Python, as well as StackOverflow. This is a definite duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6294179/10611444)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
a = ['t','e','s','t']
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == 't']
```

Inside of the list comprehension, `i` is the current index and `x` is the value at that index.

Comment: Surely you mean `[(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(a)]`? Otherwise you're only comparing for `x == 't'`, not for all elements.

Comment: @smci Sorry, I am quite confused as to what you are saying. How does what I have not find all of the indices? What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: What you have only finds the occurrences of the item 't'. Not of all items. the question said "look through a list and print out each occurrences' index number".

Comment: @smci The way I interpret the title is to look for all occurrences of a single item. Nothing in the question suggests "all items." Of course, if you can give some elaboration as to where exactly OP specified "all items" rather than a single item, that would be appreciated.

Comment: there's no need for labored sarcasm. The title clearly conflicts with the first line which says *"look through list and print out **each occurrences'** index number"*, like I said. Given a choice between interpreting it such as not to give a very reusable resource (e.g. just for item 't'), we should choose the more general way ("all items").

Answer (score 1):

With `enumerate` inside **list comprehension** for **t**,

```
>>> list1 = ['t','e','s','t']
>>> all_index = [i for i, j in enumerate(list1) if j == 't']
>>> all_index
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 3]
```

With loop for all element,

```
list1 = ['t','e','s','t']
result = {}
for e in list1:
    result[e] = [i for i, j in enumerate(list1) if j == e]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
 {'s': [2], 'e': [1], 't': [0, 3]}
```

Comment: Your 1st solution is fine. Your 2nd solution should be written without the inefficient double loop, and it should not calculate `result['t']` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with `enumerate`

```
[x[0] for x in enumerate(a) if x[1]=='t']

Out[267]: [0, 3]
```

Comment: This certainly works, but using indices is more verbose & slightly slower than tuple unpacking, like Tomothy32's answer uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_indices(my_list, item):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] == item:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

Then try it out...

```
>>> get_indices(a, "t")
[0, 3]
```

Comment: This is what `enumerate()` is for. No need for loops. List comprehensions all the way. Cleaner, shorter, more Pythonic.

Comment: But a good, working solution nonetheless. I personally prefer the looping method.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard: why? it's a clunky, obfuscated, non-Pythonic solution; less efficient and slower. It's the sort of thing a Java coder generates. It shows no understanding of Python idiom. `for i in range(len(list))` is always a code smell for `enumerate(list)`

Comment: @smci well, I am a java coder. I'm used to lots of loops. But, my point is, even though it doesn't use a builtin utility method, it still works perfectly well.

Comment: Please do not shadow built-in names like `list`. It won't hurt anything in your `get_indices` function, but in general it can lead to errors with mysterious error messages if subsequent code attempts to call `list`. And we don't want new coders reading SO answers picking up such bad habits.