# How do I return the index of a recurring character from a string in python

Tags: java, python, for-loop

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a message");

        String message = input.nextLine();

        message = message.toLowerCase();
        message = message.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            //i = the position
            System.out.println(i);
            //z = the character at position i
            char z = message.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(z);
            }
         }
}
```

This java takes a string and returns each character along with its respective index from the message. I want to make some python that does the same thing.

```py
message = raw_input( "Enter a message ")

message = message.replace(" ", "")
message = message.lower()

print message

for i in message :
    #i = each character in message
    print i
    #I want to print the position of character
    #i in the message
    print #????
```

I could use `message.index(i)`  but when there are repeat letters it will only find the first.

[How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

This question was answered using indices, but that returns the values of all occurrences of that character. I only want one index at a time.

For example, if I input the message `'hello world'` I want the output to be `0 h 1 e 2 l 3 l 4 0` etc. It was easy to do this with java because the for-loop creates the index first, then uses that index to find the character. The python code works a bit backwards, at least right now. First it finds every character in the message, but then I'm searching for that character in the message. Can I use a for-loop more similarly to the way I did in Java? is there a better way?

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly which question was the closest duplicate for you; search around the site with `[python] enumerate` until you understand how it works. BTW, the `.replaceAll` in your Java takes out more than just spaces; a Python equivalent is `message = ''.join(message.split())`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks! I'll check it out.