# Index of a list item that occurs multiple times

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the following code

```
items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd']
for x in items:
    print(x, end='')
    print(items.index(x), end='')
## out puts: a0a0b2a0c4c4d6
```

I understand that python finds the first item in the list to index, but is it possible for me to get an output of `a0a1b2a3c4c5d6` instead?
It would be optimal for me to keep using the for loop because I will be editing the list.
edit: I made a typo with the c indexes

Comment: *editing the list* (like add/remove) - while it is traversed - don't do it

Comment: use `enumerate` to get the index & the value at the same time. Or zip your list with `range(len(lst))`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you can change the list values all right. You cannot remove or add items, agreed

Comment: adding the index doesn't add much information to your data. Consider using a tuple if you want that, instead of a string

Comment: why is it still expected to output `c4c4`?

Comment: @Sayse: no it's not, probably typo

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I'm assuming that too but very used to random logic not being shared :)

Comment: A possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't add or remove items from your list as you are traversing it. If you want the output specified, you can use `enumerate` to get the items and the indices of the list.

```
items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd']
for idx, x in enumerate(items):
    print("{}{}".format(x, idx), end='')
# outputs a0a1b2a3c4c5d6
```

Comment: Your first set of parenthesis are not needed and your are concatenation with `+` instead of `format()`. I would remove the parenthesis from  `(idx, x)`  to be more dry and note that `+` is deprecated over `format()`.

Comment: Almost there. You can remove `str()` as well as format handles the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

And in case you really feel like doing it in one line:

EDIT - using `.format` or format-strings makes this shorter / more legible, as noted in the comments

```py
items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd']
print("".join("{}{}".format(e,i) for i,e in enumerate(items)))
```

For Python 3.7 you can do

```py
items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd']
print("".join(f"{e}{i}" for i, e in enumerate(items)))
```

ORIGINAL

```py
items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd']
print("".join((str(e) for item_with_index in enumerate(items) for e in item_with_index[::-1])))
```

Note that the reversal is needed (`item_with_index[::-1]`) because you want the items printed before the index but `enumerate` gives tuples with the index first.

Comment: `"".join("{}{}".format(e,i) for i,e in enumerate(items))` is shorter

Comment: True, though the first `in` should be a `for`.

Comment: true, fixed.... can also do `"".join("{1}{0}".format(*t) for t in enumerate(items))`. This could go on and on

Comment: Well your code is shorter but more readable? For most new programmers one liners like this are very confusing and not readable.

Comment: that's a question of getting used to it.

Comment: @Mike-SMT you could also argue that "See Spot Run" is very confusing and not readable to most people new to the English language :)

Comment: @b_c True. Thought I think if you are going to answer with a one liner it might help to explain each part as they are harder to grasp for most who don't use them than something like a for loop with if statements. Many of these simpler questions are asked by the new and inexperienced.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a0a1b2a3c4c5d6 instead.

```
for i, x in enumerate(items):
    print("{}{}".format(x,i), end='')
```