# Indices of equal elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list that is basicaly zeroes and ones, I want to grab all the indices of the ones from that list. How do I do it, plz. If possible, w/o loops.

```
list_example = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use a list comprehension and the `enumerate()` function.

Comment: Not that it necessarily can’t be done without loops but... why? Why is that the goal?

Comment: If you consider a list comprehension to be a loop, my suggestion won't work. You can use `enumerate`, `filter`, and `map` to do it.

Comment: [Four methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-find-indices-of-value-in-list/).  The 4th uses filter so it does it using only built-in functions (i.e. without looping in user code).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension:

```
ones_indices = [i for i, e in enumerate(list_example) if e == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.argwhere()` to obtain incides in a list whose elements satisfy a certain condition.
Below's the code:

```
import numpy as np
np.argwhere(np.array(list_example))[0]
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 7, 8]
```

where we obtain indices of all non-zero elements in `list_example`. For more specific condition checking, you could use,

```
np.argwhere(np.array(list_example==1))
```

Comment: The condition is always 'Find the indices of array elements that are non-zero, grouped by element.' from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without loops or imports you can do it this way:

```
list(zip(*list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 1, enumerate(list_example)))))[0]
# (0, 3, 7, 8)
```

or if you want lists:

```
list(map(list, zip(*list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 1, enumerate(list_example))))))[0]                                                                                               

# [0, 3, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

my attempt so far:

```
g = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
u = []
   for i in g:

    if i == 1:
        u.append(g.index (i))

print (u)
input ('continue')
```