# Python List indexing for finding number of the indexed element if the element is the same

Tags: python, arrays, list

Im trying to find the indexed version for multiple items in a list, such as

```
testarray = ["l","hello","l","l"]

for x in testarray:
    if x == "l":
        print(testarray.index(x))
```

I want the desired output to be `1, 3, 4`, but what I'm getting is `1,1,1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `list.index` returns the index of the first occurrence of the element, to fix this, you can loop through the indices and values using `enumerate`:

```
testarray = ["l", "hello", "l", "l"]

for i, x in enumerate(testarray, 1):
    if x == "l":
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
3
4
```

In `for i, x in enumerate(testarray, 1)`, `i` in the index, `x` is the value, and the second parameter `1` in `enumerate` tells it to start counting at `1` instead of by default at `0`.