# How to get list of indexes for unique values?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Having a list like this

```py
lst = ['a','b','a','c','a','b','b']
```

I'd like to get lists of indexes for each unique element to get this:

```py
indexes = {
            'a': [0,2,4],
            'b': [1,5,6],
            'c': [3]
          }
```

This is my current code, but I'm only getting the first index of each element.

```py
indexes= dict()
for el in lst:
    indexes[el] = [lst.index(el)]

>>> indexes
{'a': [0], 'b': [1], 'c': [3]}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with you code is you're overriding the same key again and again but with a different `list`, so your final dictionary contains only a single `list`.

you can avoid this behavior by using `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b"]
lst = [c for c in lst if c.strip()]  # this will remove empty strings

indexes = defaultdict(list)

for index, char in enumerate(lst):
    indexes[char].append(index)

indexes = dict(indexes)
print(indexes)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': [0, 2, 4], 'b': [1, 5, 6], 'c': [3]}
```

Comment: @GerCas I've updated the answer handling the empty strings.

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I think I didn't explain very well. I mean get rid of empty keys in output dictionary without affecting the original indexes. If I remove empty values in input list, the indexes of output dictionary change.

Comment: you'll never have an empty string because only integers are appended in that list.

Comment: Try with your current code this input list `["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b"]` and compare output dictionary with this other input list `["a", "b", "", "a", "c", "", "a", "b", "b", ""]` You'll see the indexes are different

Comment: if I understood your problem correctly I think you're looking for `indexes.pop('')`.

Comment: Exactly. Is easiest that I expected. That happens when someone is a beginner hehe. Thanks so much