# Hangman won't print word with two of same letter

Tags: python, string, list

I am making a Hangman Code for a Python class and I can't get a word that has two letters(balloon) to print both letters. This is the specific code snippet. The rest is on the link below. The code is not put together yet.

```
if letter_ask in word_string:
  location = word_string.index(letter_ask)
  word_blank_list[location] = letter_ask
  print(word_blank_list)
```

```
['-', '-', '-', '-', 'o', '-', '-']
```

[Link to my full code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18YP9kVPmxRc3r-zEATcrzHSf75aXODOS#scrollTo=TPMYZzH15Gr7)

Comment: Think about what [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) gives you. How can you get the index of the _second_ `L` in `BALLOON`? [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the index is the issue. index returns only first occurance of the element. So you need to search for [all occurances of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

So the solution could look like this:

```
letter_ask = "o"
word_string = "balloon"
word_blank_list = ["-"]*len(word_string)

if letter_ask in word_string:
    locations = [i for i, letter in enumerate(word_string) if letter == letter_ask]
    for location in locations:
        word_blank_list[location] = letter_ask

    print(word_blank_list)
```