# How can find all the indices of an elements which apperas multiple times in a particular list in python?

Tags: python

For example, if I have a list of words like `['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']`,
now for some reason in a for loop or in a function definition with `list.index(value)` method, I want to find all the indices of each word but when I reach up to 'to' word (2nd occurrence) it gives me an index of its first occurrence itself.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension solution might be:

```
lst = ['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']
{req_word: [idx for idx, word in enumerate(lst) if word == req_word] for req_word in set(lst)}
```

results in:

```
{'be': [1, 5], 'or': [2], 'to': [0, 4], 'not': [3]}
```

You can think of all other ways along the same lines as well but with `index()` you can find only one index although you can set occurrence number yourself.