# How to find the order number of item inside of a list (have duplicates)

Tags: python, list

I wanna to find the order number (index number) of the item in a list, If this list looks like this

`lst = ['a', 'v', 'c', 'a', 'b']`

I wanna get the order number of item 'a', then the ideal output will be `0,3`.

I have tried `lst.index('a')` but it only returns`0`

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `enumerate` and a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'v', 'c', 'a', 'b']
>>> [i for i, c in enumerate(lst) if c == 'a']
[0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the easiest way to do this:

```
lst = ['a', 'v', 'c', 'a', 'b']
indices = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == 'a':
       indices.append(i)

print(indices)
```